# Create an artificial correlation matrix

Tags: math, matrix, correlation

I want to do some testing of a program but I would like to have a really big matrix
Is there any tool that can generate an artificial correlation matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick `n` random `n`-dimensional vectors of numbers from -1 to 1.  Use the dot product of any 2 vectors is their correlation.  Use that fact to make a random `n` x `n` correlation matrix.

Is this really a correlation matrix?  Make each dimension into an independent standard normal distribution.  The coefficients of each vector then describes a random variable.  Those random variables have the specified correlations.  So yes, this is actually going to be a correlation matrix.

Answer (score 1):

There is a repository of sample matrix data for use in comparing algos available at the [Matrix Market](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/) - free despite the name.